# How to write a pure function in idris2 FFI?

Tags: functional-programming, ffi, idris, idris2

The idris2 has the following [example](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ffi/ffi.html#ffi-example) for FFI, which adds two integers in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

(small.c)

I followed the steps, and after linking:

```
gcc -shared smallc.c -o libsmall.so
```

and indeed the foreign function `add` can be called as shown in the example:

```
%foreign "C:add,libsmall"
add : Int -> Int -> Int

main : IO ()
main = printLn (add 70 24)
```

`:exec main` gives `94`.

However, if I just evaluate this foreign function as a pure function (`add 70 24`), then the idris2 REPL does not compute anything, and just echoes back the expression:

```
add 70 24
add 70 24
```

So, the pure foreign function only computes inside the `IO()` valued function when `:exec`. This is not consistent with what the same documentation claims:

> It is up to the programmer to declare which functions are pure, and
> which have side effects, via PrimIO

In contrast, `(+) 70 24` evaluates correctly in the REPL.

```
(+) 70 24
94
```

(The above is tested with idris2 0.6.0 under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.)

My questions are:

*How to fix the above example so that the foreign function evaluates as a stand-alone expression?*

*Why did the builtin pure functions such as `(+)` work? Is it because they use `RefC` or some different methods?*

Related:

[How to write a pure String to String function in Haskell FFI to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16888135/4196578)

[How to read a C/C++ array from idris2 FFI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77006955/4196578)

Comment: what does `show (add 70 24)` output?

Comment: @joel,  it shows `prim__cast_IntString (add 70 24)`.