# How to get normal values from fastPack in Idris?

Tags: idris, idris2

I am confused about the difference between `pack` and `fastPack` functions in Idris2 (as of 0.7.0). Both have the same signature:

```
:t pack
Prelude.pack : List Char -> String
:t fastPack
Prelude.fastPack : List Char -> String
```

`pack` works as advertised and converts a list of `Char`s into a `String`.

```
pack ['a'] ++ pack ['b']
```

renders:

```
"ab"
```

But I can't seem to get `String`s out of `fastPack`.

```
fastPack ['a'] ++ fastPack ['b']
```

renders:

```
prim__strAppend (fastPack ['a']) (fastPack ['b'])
```

I am not sure whether some laziness is going on here. But some of the base code I am testing uses `fastPack`, so the result expression becomes large very quickly.

*Is there a way to get the normal string value out of these fastPack expressions?*

(In this example, "ab" from `prim__strAppend (fastPack ['a']) (fastPack ['b'])`. I tried `show` and `force`, to no avail.)

Comment: most of your question is the same as your [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77016059/5986907)

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused about the difference between `pack` and `fastPack` functions in Idris2

[`pack`](https://idris-lang.org/docs/idris2/current/prelude_docs/docs/Prelude.Types.html#Prelude.Types.pack) is [implemented in Idris](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/libs/prelude/Prelude/Types.idr#L847-L851):

> ```idris
> ||| Turns a list of characters into a string.
> public export
> pack : List Char -> String
> pack [] = ""
> pack (x :: xs) = strCons x (pack XS)
> ```

[`fastPpack`](https://idris-lang.org/docs/idris2/current/prelude_docs/docs/Prelude.Types.html#Prelude.Types.fastPack) is a [foreign function](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/libs/prelude/Prelude/Types.idr#L853-L858):

> ```idris
> %foreign
>     "scheme:string-pack"
>     "RefC:fastPack"
>     "javascript:lambda:(xs)=>__prim_idris2js_array(xs).join('')"
> export
> fastPack : List Char -> String
> ```

The ECMAScript implementation just uses [`Array.prototype.join`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.join).

The Scheme implementation [looks like this](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/support/chez/support.ss#L155) in the Chez backend:

> ```scheme
> (define (string-pack xs) (list->string xs))
> ```

And [in the Gambit backend](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/support/gambit/support.scm#L135-L136):

> ```scheme
> (define-macro (string-pack xs)
>   `(apply string ,xs))
> ```

And [in the Racket backend](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/support/racket/support.rkt#L160):

> ```scheme
> (define (string-pack xs) (list->string xs))
> ```

For the C backend, it is [implemented like this](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/support/refc/stringOps.c#L90-L111):

> ```c
> char *fastPack(Value *charList) {
>   Value_Constructor *current;
>
>   int l = 0;
>   current = (Value_Constructor *)charList;
>   while (current->total == 2) {
>     l++;
>     current = (Value_Constructor *)current->args[1];
>   }
>
>   char *retVal = malloc(l + 1);
>   retVal[l] = 0;
>
>   int i = 0;
>   current = (Value_Constructor *)charList;
>   while (current->total == 2) {
>     retVal[i++] = ((Value_Char *)current->args[0])->c;
>     current = (Value_Constructor *)current->args[1];
>   }
>
>   return retVal;
> }
> ```

> *Is there a way to get the normal string value out of these fastPack expressions?*

That requires far more intimacy with [Idris's FFI](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ffi/) than I possess.

Interestingly, there is a [`%transform`](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pragmas.html#transform) defined which will [automatically replace `pack` with `fastPack`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/libs/prelude/Prelude/Types.idr#L860-L861):

> ```idris
> -- always use 'fastPack' at run time
> %transform "fastPack" pack = fastPack
> ```